# Using Shopify API in different Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, model-view-controller, shopify

I need to get the current shop's domain (I do this using `ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.domain`). This works in the HomeController and can display it in `home/index.html.erb`. But, when I try to call `ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.domain` in my CustomController to display in a different view, I get the error `Missing site URI`.

I think this is because once the user leaves the home/index view it no longer has access to that Shop instance. So, how can I recreate that instance in my CustomController if I don't know the id. For example, this works:

```
@shop = Shop.find(1)
@domain = @shop.shopify_domain
```

But, I will not always know the shop's `id` in the model.

Or, maybe I am approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: How is your controller in any way related to what resources in the api you can access? Are you talking about accessing the shop from liquid or from your backend controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late to the party but using `around_filter :shopify_session` in your controller should fix this. If it doesn't, ensure that the controller is inheriting from the `AuthenticatedController`.

Example:

```
class CustomerController < AuthenticatedController
  around_filter :shopify_session

  def shops
    @shop = ShopifyAPI::Shop.find(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I was actually just establishing a new session on every page since I couldn't find an answer. But I just tested this out and it works.